# svyboxplot results change when using different categories versus subsets

Tags: r, boxplot, survey

I am new to the survey package and have a mystery problem. I have made data weights using anesrake package and then created a survey design.

I have a problem when using svyboxplot and a grouping variable:
It draws similar boxplots for each grouping category, which is not true

When I studied the problem subsetting each of my category (15 of them)
the values are different for each area / different boxplots for each area.

Can anyone help me? I am desperate!

Here`s sample to test

```
library(tidyverse)

col <- tibble(
name = c("seura 1", "seura 2", "seura 3", "seura 4", "seura 5", "seura 6", "seura 7", "seura 8", "seura 9"
, "seura 10", "seura 11", "seura 12"),
riistakeskus = c("Keski-Suomi","Keski-Suomi","Keski-Suomi","Keski-Suomi","Keski-Suomi","Satakunta","Satakunta",
"Satakunta","Uusimaa", "Uusimaa","Uusimaa","Uusimaa"),
hirvi_sarvisuositus = c(1,4,5,3,7,5,3,4,6,5,8,9),
weights = c(1.1461438,1.1461438,1.1461438,1.1461438,1.1461438,0.5107815,0.5107815,0.5107815,2.0461937,
2.0461937,2.0461937,2.0461937)
)
```

```
library(survey)

my_des1 <- svydesign(data = col, weights = ~weights, ids = ~1)
b <- svyboxplot(hirvi_sarvisuositus~factor(riistakeskus), my_des1, all.outliers = F, ylim = c(0,10))
svyboxplot(hirvi_sarvisuositus~1, subset(my_des1, riistakeskus == "Keski-Suomi"), ylim = c(0,10))
svyboxplot(hirvi_sarvisuositus~1, subset(my_des1, riistakeskus == "Satakunta"), ylim = c(0,10))
svyboxplot(hirvi_sarvisuositus~1, subset(my_des1, riistakeskus == "Uusimaa"), ylim = c(0,10))
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and would like to add to Anthonys answer, but I cannot comment yet.

There is an error in `survey:::svyboxplot.default` as Anthony indicates but it does not seem to have anything to do with data points. If you use `keep.var = FALSE` with `FUN=svyquantile` it does return the overall quantiles instead of the group specific quantiles.

Compare

```
svyby(~hirvi_sarvisuositus, ~riistakeskus, my_des1, svyquantile, ci = FALSE, 
        keep.var = FALSE, quantiles = c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1), 
        na.rm = TRUE)
```

with

```
svyquantile(~hirvi_sarvisuositus, my_des1, 
        quantiles = c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1), 
        na.rm = TRUE)
```

Note that svyquantile can not compute the SE for some quantiles.

If you use `keep.var=TRUE` instead and try to extract the CIs, you get quantiles by group.

```
svyby(~hirvi_sarvisuositus, ~riistakeskus, my_des1, svyquantile,
         quantiles = c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1), ci=TRUE, na.rm = TRUE, 
  keep.var = TRUE, vartype = "ci")
```

However, you can't change the `svyquantile` function options when calling `svyboxplot`. This needs to be fixed in the package. You could built your boxplots yourself instead. A simple base R solution:

```
q <- svyby(~hirvi_sarvisuositus, ~riistakeskus, my_des1, svyquantile,       
    quantiles = c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1), na.rm = TRUE, ci=TRUE, 
    keep.var = TRUE, 
    vartype = "ci")

boxstats <- q[,2:6]

bxp(list(stats=t(as.matrix(boxstats)),
         n = c(100,100,100),
         names = rownames(boxstats)))
```

[image: base R boxplot constructed with svyby-values]

To prevent whiskers inside the box, you can change qrule to use a different way to calculate quantiles (e.g. `qrule="hf7"` for the quantile() default).

An alternative solution would be to use a weighted boxplot from ggplot2:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=col, aes(y=hirvi_sarvisuositus, x=factor(riistakeskus), weight=weights)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image: weighted geom_boxplot solution using ggplot2]

Please note that ggplot2 uses a slightly different estimation of the hinges, see help(geom_boxplot), which influences the results for low N.

Answer (score 0):

great reproducible example, thank you!  this result especially looks silly

```
svyboxplot(hirvi_sarvisuositus~riistakeskus,my_des1,ylim=c(0,10))
```

i think this largely happens because `svyquantile` just needs more data points to get reasonable estimates..

if you look at the code inside `survey:::svyboxplot.default` you can find the line that produces all of the same quantile results

```
svyby(~hirvi_sarvisuositus, ~riistakeskus, my_des1, svyquantile, ci = FALSE, 
        keep.var = FALSE, quantiles = c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1), 
        na.rm = TRUE)
```

not sure if this is really a bug that the `survey` package author would want to fix..  perhaps consider using the `?bxp` function if your use case has that small of a dataset?